# Keyboard navigation not working on sudden google image CAPTCHA

Tags: support

I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640792/how-to-convert-session-data-to-sessionstatestoredata-type-in-custom-session-stat/30673807#30673807), and was unexpectedly confronted with a google image CAPTCHA:

[image]

What I have found is that these google image CAPTCHAs simply do not support proper [keyboard navigation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-features-firefox-make-firefox-and-we) -- there is no way to tab to the correct images and pick them.  This is a problem for me, since (after decades of mouse use) I have mild tendonitis and so must keep my hands on the keyboard as much as possible to eliminate discomfort.

Unfortunately, google audio CAPTCHAs are generally incomprehensible -- and I was not able to tab to the headphones button anyway.

If you must confront pre-existing, logged-in users with CAPTCHAs, please shift the keyboard focus to the CAPTCHA, and choose a CAPTCHA technology that is more accessible to keyboard users (e.g., software developers.)  I have stopped contributing to other sites that have switched to image captchas and so require much more extensive mouse interaction.

Comment: _Unfortunately, google audio CAPTCHAs are generally incomprehensible_ - This is an aside but perhaps we could also report this as a bug to Google.

Comment: You must be well written bot, with 11k reputation :)

Comment: While I support telling Google about this, I'm not sure it's worth spending much time on it as this type of CAPTCHA happens so infrequently.

Comment: @TLama Must be [one of these bots](https://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: Please report here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha or to their twitter account https://twitter.com/recaptcha